# How to remove https from admin panel in magento database as getting 403 error

Tags: php, magento

I have wrongly activate secure web config and written 'https' where it 
is 'http'. I have checked database table : core_config_data. 
web/secure/use_in_frontend and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml is '0' and 
web/secure/offloader_header is SSL_OFFLOADED.

Also remove cache and session data. Still I didn't get any solution.

Please do the needfull as admin panel is redirecting to 'https' instead 
of 'http'

Comment: restarting your apache/nginx after disabling all cache could help

Answer (score 28):

Reset “Use Secure in Front End or Admin” in Database – Magento

I ran into an issue this week where I switched on SSL on a development site and then realized the SSL cert was not installed correctly. This is a big issue in Magento because there is no way to get back to the admin to switch it back off.

If this ever happens do the following to switch back:

1. Open up your admin panel (cPanel or other)
2. Go to phpMyAdmin (if MySql)
3. Find your Magento Database
4. Find table “core_config_data”
5. Look for the columns “web/secure/use_in_frontend” and “web/secure/use_in_adminhtml”
6. Edit both values, make them equal to “0”

After this is done you will be back in action.

- See more at: https://mrumair.com

Comment: great answer, just saved me.

Comment: This is the correct answer but as @Gus points out if you have cache on you will need to clear it after you make these changes.

Comment: I am using 1.9 magneto but it not there in core_config_data 
web/secure/use_in_frontend” and “web/secure/use_in_adminhtml

Comment: The link at `mrumair.com` was edited in recently, but it is dead for me here. Does it (not) work for anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

AFter making the above changes delete your website cache,  Either FTP to your public directory or use your file manager from your hosting agreement and delete the contents of the /var/cache folder.  I had this exact issue and as soon as i deleted my cache it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of web/secure/base_url path in core_config_data.

You can change this from https to http.

Comment: What's the full url there?

Comment: You can try to change this to http:// www.stanhobbies.com/ (remove space). For what it's worth.

Comment: There is no space in URL and I have replaced with old backup, still admin is going to https